# How do I change from the Checkbutton on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm very new to Tkinter and don't really know how to use it.
I looked up some similar code and found a solution for how to get the text boxes(e1)(e6) I use to register the values, but the downside was that I needed to use the Checkbox that's in line 52.
Does anyone know how I could stop using the checkbox, and just put in the values without having to click the checkbox?

```
#importerar tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#All calculations are made here, which are then displayed and registered before you save the receipt.

def show():
    totalt = 0
    if (japp.get()):
        pris = int(e1.get())
        kvk = int(e6.get())
        totalt = int(pris * kvk)
        tempList = [[e1.get(), e6.get(), totalt]]
        tempList.sort(key=lambda e: e[1], reverse=True)
        for i, (pris, kvk, totalt) in enumerate(tempList, start=1):
            listBox.insert("", "end", values=(pris, kvk, totalt))

    sum1 = 0.0
    for lmao in listBox.get_children():
        sum1 += float(listBox.item(lmao, 'values')[2])
    totaltText.set(sum1)

#Here the receipt is saved, geom that it goes through each number and then enters it in the txt file.

def spara():
    for lmao in listBox.get_children():
        pris = str(listBox.item(lmao, 'values')[0])
        kvk = str(listBox.item(lmao, 'values')[1])
        totalt = str(listBox.item(lmao, 'values')[2])

    txt = open("Kvitto.txt", "w")
    txt.write("kvantitet: " + kvk + ". Pris per vara: " + pris + ". total kostnad: " + totalt + ". ")
    txt.close


hej = Tk()
hej.title("Kvitto system")
hej.geometry("650x650")
global e1
global totaltText
global balText

totaltText = StringVar()
balText = IntVar()

#all text som visas

Label(hej, text="Kvitto system", font="arial 22 bold" ,bg="white").place(x=5, y=10)
Label(hej, text="Antal", font="arial 13").place(x=10, y=80)

japp = IntVar()
Checkbutton(hej, text="Kostnad per styck", variable=japp).place(x=10, y=50)

#skriv rutorna, där man svarar på kvantitet(e6) och kostnad(e1)

e1 = Entry(hej)
e1.place(x=200, y=80)

e6 = Entry(hej)
e6.place(x=200, y=50)

totalt = Label(hej, text="", font="arial 22 bold", textvariable=totaltText)
totalt.place(x=650, y=10)

#Alla knappar som används i programmet

Button(hej, text="Lägg till varor", command=show, height=3, width=13).place(x=10, y=220)
cols = ('Pris', 'Kvantitet', 'total kostnad')
listBox = ttk.Treeview(hej, columns=cols, show='headings')

Button(hej, text="Spara Kvitto", command=spara, height=3, width=13).place(x=150, y=220)

for col in cols:
    listBox.heading(col, text=col)
    listBox.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
    listBox.place(x=10, y=300)


hej.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, just remove this checkbox and everything associated with it, like checks about this checkbox etc.

For starter, adjust tabulation after removing these lines:

```
if (japp.get()):
...
japp = IntVar()
Checkbutton(hej, text="Kostnad per styck", variable=japp).place(x=10, y=50)
```

Offtop:

That's strange, if you created that code, you should be able to modify it. First thing you should do is organize your code in classes, to be easier to manage and debug...

Comment: Thanks for helping me.
Its not my personal code, its a group project with a friend, and I'm not actively doing the coding part of the project, but while he is sick I had to take over for a short while.

Comment: I see, that's understandable why you didn't know where to look for. Enjoy the project and I wish you luck :D